# Type to mock must be an interface or an abstract or non-sealed class

Tags: .net, vb.net, unit-testing, moq

I'm using Moq to mock the following class in VB:

```
Public class Factory(Of T)
  Inherits Factory

  Public Overridable Shadows Readonly Property Model() as TModel
    Get
       ..
    End Get
  End Property
```

When I attempt to use Moq to mock the Model property in a unit test like so:

```
Dim factory As New Mock(of Factory(Of TestModel))
factory.Setup(Function(i) i.Model).Returns(new TestModel With { .. })
```

This fails with the error:

> System.ArgumentException: Type to mock must be an interface or an
>   abstract or non-sealed class.  ---> System.TypeLoadException: Access
>   is denied:
>   'PA.PSP.PFAD.Mvc.PFADFactory`1[PA.PSP.PFAD.Mvc.OrderExtensionsTest+TestModel]'.
>   Result StackTrace:     at
>   System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.TermCreateClass(RuntimeModule
>   module, Int32 tk, ObjectHandleOnStack type)    at
>   System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.CreateTypeNoLock()    at
>   System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.CreateType()    at
>   Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.Emitters.AbstractTypeEmitter.CreateType(TypeBuilder
>   type)    at
>   Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.Emitters.AbstractTypeEmitter.BuildType()
>   at
>   Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.ClassProxyGenerator.GenerateType(String
>   name, Type[] interfaces, INamingScope namingScope)

Any idea why because while it's not an interface or abstract, it's not sealed (doesn't define NotInheritable in VB)....

Comment: You: `Dim factory As New Mock(of Factory(Of TestModel))` I wonder if the nested `TestModel` class is public, and if its containing class `OrderExtensionsTest` is public as well? Moq needs to create a class "on the fly" which derives from `Factory(Of TestModel)` (or `PFADFactory(Of TestModel)` as it is called in the error text).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to make Model() virtual ?